# If the greek word "autou" "his " is the original word used in Hebrews 1:8, why is the greek word "sou" "your " preferred by most translations?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrews

Hebrews 1:8 NIV But about the Son he says, “Your throne, O God, will last for ever and ever; a scepter of justice will be the scepter of **your** kingdom.

Hebrews 1:8 NASB But regarding the Son He says, “YOUR THRONE, GOD, IS FOREVER AND EVER, AND THE SCEPTER OF RIGHTEOUSNESS IS THE SCEPTER OF **HIS** KINGDOM

Comment: You will need to provide evidence that your initial assertion is true - the very fact that NA28/UBS5 (the most widely used text) has "sou" suggests that most believe that, based on the considerable evidence they proffer, that "sou" is the original reading.  None of the other texts (eg, Byzantine, etc) offer any evidence for the reading "autou".

Comment: For a summary of the evidence about what is original, see UBS5 and Metzger's "Textual commentary on the GNT".  Even the NWT has "your kingdom".

Comment: @Dottard. Michael16's answer lightly touched on the subject and cited Sinaiticus, Vaticanus and P46 in his answer to my Q "Who is this "His" in Hebrews 1:8 if the Father is speaking to the Son? In addition, in discussing this problem the UBS Committee noted that most of the very oldest and best manuscripts (p46 - circa 200 A.D.; 'Aleph' - 4th century; and B - 4th century) all agree that the original wording was “his (autou) kingdom.” So his answer inspire me to look deeper into this subject. Do you think the proof cited by Michael16 is spurious?

Comment: Aleph and B are those same Sinaiticus and vsticanus. Why are you dwelling into it? Yes these are better mss and this might be the right reading but we can even use conjectures to support style and readability. No big deal. It's shifted to third person in the sentence for using "his".

Comment: No. That Q, merely is a referent identification Q. This Q, is about translation philosophy.

Comment: I answered there that it's a decision for readability by assuming the "your" is accurate or maybe it's a conjecture. Read the books like Text of the NT Metzger Ehrman. Editorial decision. Conjectures are allowed.

Comment: 'Thy throne . . . thy kingdom' is the translation given by KJV/YLT/Tyndale/JND/DRB and Wycliffe.

Comment: Alex - your question is not the right question.  If you want to ask about the textual problem in Hebrews 1:8, then ask that.  As it stands, you question is about the translation, and not the textual problem.

Comment: @Dottard..So why are you trying to close it, if as it stands my Q is about the translation. 1st you ask me for proof, when I provided them, now you seek to close it.Why are some of your Questions  about the trinity, which is not even mentioned in the bible are not closed,? when a Q like this one is voted to be closed. Why not answer this Q as a textual problem rather than closing it?

Comment: There is no way to prove that *autou* is the "original" reading.  The fact that some older manuscripts contain the reading is no proof.  Some of the oldest manuscripts of Revelation contain 616 instead of 666.